# Integrating a 2-form

Tags: integration, differential-forms

Integrate the 2-form $\omega=\frac1x dy\wedge dz-\frac1y dx\wedge dz$ over the following surface:

The top half of the unit sphere using the following parametrization.

$(r,\theta)\to (r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta,\sqrt{1-r^2})$, where $0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi$ and $0\leq r\leq 1$.

I am currently working through "A Geometric Approach to Differential Forms" by David Bachman, which gives a rather informal introduction to the topic, and this is a task, which I am unable to solve.

The reason I struggle here is that I have the following formula:

$\int_M \omega =\int_R \omega_{\phi(x,y)}\left(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}(x,y),\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y}(x,y)\right) dx\wedge dy$.

And I now want to integrate the 2-form above, which is part $dy\wedge dz$ and $dx\wedge dz$.

So I am confused on how to apply this formula in this case, where we have "$dx\wedge dz-dy\wedge dz$" and not just "$dx\wedge dy$". Can you help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The integral is a linear operation: $\int (f \, dy \wedge dz + g \, dx \wedge dz) = \int f \, dy \wedge dz + \int g \, dx \wedge dz$.

Comment: Probably easier to do everything in term of $r, \theta$. You may plug in $dx=\cos\theta dr-r\sin\theta d\theta$, $dy=\sin\theta dr+r\cos\theta d\theta$, $dz=-\frac{r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}dr$, and integrate $dr\wedge d\theta$...

Comment: @AlexProvost Yes, but I tried to avoid that.

Comment: You're misunderstanding your formula. The $\phi(x,y)$ is the parametrization of your surface $M$, which, in your case makes it $\phi(r,\theta)$. Both integrals should be rewritten as a $dr\wedge d\theta$ integral.

Comment: @TedShifrin After a break I now turned back to this calculation and was able to solve it in the answer below. However there are still some misunderstandings on my part, and I hope there can be an answer given. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now solved this as follows.

I calculate the integrals seperatly. So first I calculate the integral for $\frac{1}{x} dy\wedge dz$

Then
$\int_M \frac{1}{x}dy\wedge dz=\int_R \frac{1}{r\cos(\theta)} \left(\left\langle \cos(\theta),\sin(\theta),\frac{-r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\right\rangle,\left\langle-r\sin(\theta),r\cos(\theta),0\right\rangle\right)dr\wedge d\theta$

Where $\langle\cdot\rangle$ just notes a vector.

Now to respect $dy\wedge dz$ it seems I have to calculate the determinant given by the y- and z-coordinates. Hence

$\int_R \frac{1}{r\cos(\theta)}\begin{vmatrix}\sin(\theta)& r\cos(\theta)\\ \frac{-r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}&0\end{vmatrix}dr\wedge d\theta=\int_R \frac{r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}dr\wedge d\theta=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 \frac{r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}dr\,d\theta=2\pi$

And with a similar calculation we achiev

$\int_M -\frac{1}{y}dx\wedge dz=2\pi$.

So the result is $2\pi+2\pi=4\pi$, which is correct according to the solutions in the named book.

One question remains: How does the integral "remember" the coordinates we started with after employing the formula for the parametrization.
In the first integral I respected y- and z-coordinate.

In the second integral I take the determinant with regards to the x- and z-coordinate, which leads to

$\begin{vmatrix}\cos(\theta)&-r\sin(\theta)\\ \frac{-r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}&0\end{vmatrix}$.

Since the solution is correct, I assume that this is the right way to do it, but I do not know why we have to take these specific determinants, as the formula is the same in both cases. So how is $dx\wedge dz$ respectively $dy\wedge dz$ respected in the formula?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to pull back $dy$ and $dz$, for example, by $\phi$, and then wedge them. That is the determinant of the appropriate minor of the derivative matrix of the mapping.

Comment: You might find my various YouTube lectures on forms, surface integrals, etc., useful. See the link in my profile.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for your reply. Unfortunatly the book I uses does not introduce pullbacks. At the moment I do not have the time to watch a long series of videos, but if you recommand a few I might take a look. Besides that I would appreciate to see your solution to this exercise, because at the moment I do not understand what exactly you mean.

Comment: So Bachman has defined the integral of the $2$-form with the Jacobian determinant in there. What do you mean the formula is the same in both cases? You use the $xy$-part of the derivative matrix to get $dx\wedge dy = \frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (r,\theta)} dr\wedge d\theta$, $dy\wedge dz = \frac{\partial (y,z)}{\partial (r,\theta)}dr\wedge d\theta$, etc. I don't understand what your question is at this point.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. Yeah, that was some sort of blackout on my end. Thank you.